# How to move these objects with touch?

Tags: swift, touch

Having some troubles figuring out how to move these objects with touch. Simply touching them and moving them is what i'm focusing on figuring out right now. Below I will add most of the code from GameScene.swift, it should be enough to help.. I think. However, I do have another class called Tetromino.swift and if you need that to help answer my question, let me know and I will add it in!

I've added touchesBegan, touchesMoved, and touchesEnded and i've been trying some different things but cannot get the objects to move - so the code isn't correct in them. The objects are squares that make up different Tetromino pieces. Thanks in advance!

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

var activeTetromino1 = Tetromino()
var activeTetromino2 = Tetromino()
var activeTetromino3 = Tetromino()

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    // Setup scene
    self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

    activeTetromino1 = Tetromino(drawTetrominoAtPoint(location: CGPoint(x: frame.width / 4, y: frame.height / 4)))
    activeTetromino2 = Tetromino(drawTetrominoAtPoint(location: CGPoint(x: frame.width / 2, y: frame.height / 4)))
    activeTetromino3 = Tetromino(drawTetrominoAtPoint(location: CGPoint(x: frame.width / 4 * 3, y: frame.height / 4)))

}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch: AnyObject in (touches) {
        //let location = touch.location(in: self)
        drawTetrominoAtPoint(location: touch.location(in: self))
        /*
        if activeTetromino1.contains(location) {
            activeTetromino1.position = location
        }
        */
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch: AnyObject in (touches) {
        drawTetrominoAtPoint(location: touch.location(in: self))

        /*
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        if activeTetromino1.contains(location) {
            activeTetromino1.position = location
        }
        */
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    //activeTetromino1 = Tetromino(position = CGPoint(x: frame.width / 4, y: frame.height / 4))
}


override func update(_ currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    // Called before each frame is rendered
}

func drawTetrominoAtPoint(location: CGPoint) {
    let t = Tetromino()
    for row in 0..<t.bitmap.count {
        for col in 0..<t.bitmap[row].count {
            if t.bitmap[row][col] > 0 {
                let block = t.bitmap[row][col]
                let square = SKSpriteNode(color: colors[block], size: CGSize(width: blockSize, height: blockSize))
                square.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0)
                square.position = CGPoint(x: col * Int(blockSize) + col, y: -row * Int(blockSize) + -row)
                square.position.x += location.x
                square.position.y += location.y
                self.addChild(square)
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It seems a bit awkward that you draw the _parts_ of each tetromino as a separate childSprite of the _scene_ . It would make things a lot easier if the tetromino itself had a sprite-property with all the necessary squares added as children in the correct position. If you simply added this sprite to the scene, you could simply modify the `tetromino.sprite.position` whenever required.

Comment: @T.BenjaminLarsen You are right, that seems like a way better approach. I'm fairly new to coding and Swift.. how should I make the Tetromino have a sprite-property with all the necessary squares added as children in the right positions? Thank you for the reply!

Comment: I would guess the logic from your drawTetrominoAtPoint could be moved to the Tetromino-class.